# rostopic pub: "required argument is not a float" while sending Float32MultiArray

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, 
I would like to run one of my robot's wheel with a ros command in a terminal. 
The function I use need two parameters so I wanted to use Float32MultiArray.

My arduino code ressembles to the following one:

```
float x,y;
----------
/*callback*/
void cmd(const std_msgs::Float32MultiArray& array){
  x = a.data[0];  
  y = a.data[1];  
  motor1.run(x,y); }
----------
/*suscriber*/
ros::Subscriber sub("cmd", &cmd);
```

In a terminal, I type the following command:

```
rostopic pub /cmd std_msgs/Float32MultiArray "layout:
 dim:
 - label: "run"
 size: 2
 stride: 1
 data_offset:0
data:[100 100]" --once
```

However, I have the following error:

```
[WARN] [..]: Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: : 'required argument is not a float' when writing 'label: run
size: 2
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Kindest regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323958/rostopic-pub:-%22required-argument-is-not-a-float%22-while-sending-float32multiarray./) by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-05-28**:
Could you precise what does your `(x, y)` variables stand for? If they are velocities, we could come up with a more natural/coherent way to publish them.

**Comment by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on 2019-05-29**:
In fact, (x,y) variables stands for the position (degrees) the robot has to reach and its speed (rpm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following command will publish your data and give you access to your two parameters.

```
rostopic pub /cmd std_msgs/Float32MultiArray '{data: [100, 100]}' --once
```

You're not using the `layout` in your code so we don't need to set it in this use case. The error you had is mainly because the published data is not formatted correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) with karma: 188 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on 2019-05-29**:
Indeed, it was the cause of the error. Thank you Jasmin :)